# Get mapping value with JSON-RPC → eth_getStorageAt || eth_call

Tags: json-rpc, mapping

How do I get mapping values from my contract with JSON-RPC (**without** using web3.js)?

In my contract:

```
struct Data {
  address key;
  string value;
}
mapping(bytes32 => Data) public values;
```

I can't figure out what to use as 'data' to get $contract.values($key)

```
{
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "eth_getStorageAt",
        params: [
          ???,
          '0x000',
          "latest"
        ],
        id: "1"
}
```

Or

```
{
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "eth_call",
        params: [{
         data:data,
         from:'0x000',
         to: '0x000'
        }, 'latest']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find answer on how to use eth_getStorageAt.

But you can use eth_call with the following data.

```
const part1 = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('values(bytes32)');
const part2 = //bytes32 mapping key
const data =  part1 + part2;
```